# How to prove the commutation relation $[\hat{q}(t), \hat{p}(t)]=i\hbar$ in the photon states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In an electromagnetic filed, if we choose:

$$E_x(z,t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{V\epsilon_0}}\omega q(t)\sin(kz)$$ 
$$\text {and}$$
$$cB_y(z,t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{V\epsilon_0}}p(t)\cos(kz)$$

How to prove the commutation relation: $$[\hat{q}(t), \hat{p}(t)]=i\hbar$$ for the photon states?

Comment: What makes you say that relation holds?

Comment: Dear Prof. Legolasov, I saw it from the lecture note of the MIT OCW: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_06.pdf  page 48. Could you give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: I'd say it's a postulate of quantum mechanics. You can also check it's consistent with the postulate that photon is a boson with commutation relation 5.41

Comment: You can see from 5.39 that the EM fiel can be seen as an harmonic oscillator (in a multimode description it will be a collection of harmonic oscillators). We can promote the position and momentum coordinates to operators following the description of the quantum harmonic oscillator (so with the commutation relations you mentioned).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed such a postulation is self-consistent, giving the boson commutation relation and letting the Heisenberg motion equation identical to that of the Maxwell equation result ($p'_H(t)=-w^2q(t)$ and $q'_H(t)=p(t)$, from the homework). But I still feel uncomfortable with such postulation because $[x, p]=i\hbar$ can be directly derived by working $[\hat{x}, \hat{p}]$ on a plane wave $Ae^{ikx}$. We cannot write the $\hat{p}$ into $\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$ right? and what is the counterpart of the 'plane wave' for the photon states?

Comment: You can write $\hat{p}$ into $-i\hbar \partial_x$, if you are dealing with a position state $\langle x|$. All the rules that you learned in QM applies. I'm not sure I understand your second question. Maybe it can be useful to know that you can write the field operator as $\hat{E}(r,t)$  $\propto\sum_l \hat{a}_l $$e^{k_l r-\omega_l t}$

Comment: I think I understand it now. I should not be fixated on the plane wave. Deriving $[x,p]=i\hbar$ from the derivation of the $|x\rangle$ is merely building the connection between the Schrodinger picture and Heisenberg picture. The postulated quantum condition $[\hat{q},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$ should come first (and such construction agree well with the Maxwell relations). Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is canonical quantization essentially. To quantize a system you need to promote the Lie brackets to commutators, i.e. that $[q,p]=i\hbar$ holds.